# Create a lnk in PowerShell/batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, lnk

I want to create a shortcut in batch/PowerShell and found this command (the variable `id` is set beforehand):

```
powershell "$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('%userprofile%\Desktop\Steamlink.lnk');$s.TargetPath='C:\Meins\Steam\Steam.exe -applaunch %id%';$s.Save()
```

The script itself works fine. However, there's a little problem: The target of the link created by this command is surrounded in double quotes, which breaks it...

That means that, if I look at the properties of the link, in the target there is for that example `C:\Meins\Steam\Steam.exe -applaunch 248390` INCLUSIVE double quotes, which prevents the Explorer from recognizing it.

Comment: Are you trying to escape characters? https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html

Comment: no, there are double quotes in the generated link which aren't in the command

Comment: You need to define the arguments in `$s.Arguments` not include them in `$s.TargetPath`

Comment: thanks! that worked!